SDL3 C#: SDL_DestroyWindow() gives 'Invalid window' error despite valid window creation
I am writing a program to create an SDL3 window in C#.
I have compiled SDL3 2.30.5 code from the following repository: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL under Win x64 using Rider 2024.1.2.
Here is the code I'm trying to run:
using SDL3;

namespace SDL3Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool _loop;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (SDL.Init(SDL.InitFlags.Video) < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: {SDL.GetError()}");
                return;
            }

            var window = SDL.CreateWindow("SDL Create Window", 800, 600, SDL.WindowFlags.OpenGL);

            if (window == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Window could not be created! SDL_Error: {SDL.GetError()}");
                return;
            }

            _loop = true;

            while (_loop)
            {
                while (SDL.PollEvent(out var sdlEvent) != 0)
                {
                    if (sdlEvent == SDL.EventType.Quit)
                    {
                        _loop = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            SDL.DestroyWindow(window);

            Console.WriteLine($"SDL_Error: {SDL.GetError()}");

            SDL.Quit();
        }
    }
}

Here is the CreateWindow function:
[LibraryImport(SDLLibrary)]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvCdecl) })]
private static unsafe partial IntPtr SDL_CreateWindow(byte* title, int w, int h, WindowFlags flags);

public static unsafe IntPtr CreateWindow(string? title, int w, int h, WindowFlags flags)
{
    var utf8TitleBufSize = Utf8Size(title);
    var utf8Title = stackalloc byte[utf8TitleBufSize];
    return SDL_CreateWindow(Utf8Encode(title, utf8Title, utf8TitleBufSize), w, h, flags);
}

And here's the DestroyWindow function:
[LibraryImport(SDLLibrary, EntryPoint = "SDL_DestroyWindow")]
[UnmanagedCallConv(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvCdecl) })]
public static unsafe partial void DestroyWindow(IntPtr window);

Helper functions:
private static int Utf8Size(string? str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return str.Length * 4 + 1;
}

private static unsafe byte* Utf8Encode(string? str, byte* buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return (byte*)0;
    }
    fixed (char* strPtr = str)
    {
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPtr, str.Length + 1, buffer, bufferSize);
    }
    return buffer;
}

private static unsafe string? UTF8_ToManaged(IntPtr s, bool freePtr = false)
{
    if (s == IntPtr.Zero) return null;

    var ptr = (byte*)s;
    while (*ptr != 0) ptr++;

    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte*)s, (int)(ptr - (byte*)s));

    if (freePtr) Free(s);
    return result;
}

The problem is that when I call SDL.DestroyWindow(window);, I get the error SDL_Error: Invalid window through GetError.
What could be causing this issue?

I imagine you ended your program by closing the window.  Thus destroying it before your code got to it.

@HansPassant Are you saying that clicking the close button of a window automatically destroys it without the need for DestroyWindow to be active?

I moved DestroyWindow to the Quit event handler. At the time of calling DestroyWindow, the window stores a link, but I get an Invalid window error and the window does not close.

What does SDL.PollEvent do? Out of curiosity why are you using bare pointers for the strings and not just passing them as normal Ansi strings, or as byte arrays?

@Charlieface PollEvent checks if there is any event, and if so, passes its type. I don't use ANSI because I need Unicode. Why not a byte array is difficult to say. In SDL3, the called method has the following signature: SDL_Window* SDL_CreateWindow(const char *title, int w, int h, SDL_WindowFlags flags); and byte* is what I have found in other wrappers and what works. If you have any ideas on how to do it better, I'd be happy to take a look.
